# Background CSS Image

Tags: css, background-image, transparency, opacity, fadeout

I have a fairly complex webpage and am looking to have a image in the background that is seen through all out all the div layers. Please take a look at http://va.in-design.com for the code. No matter what I try, I am able to only get some of the menu to show. Some settings make it show when the menu on the page is accessed (hovered over). Can someone give me a pointer on the best way to do this. Also, is there anything available out there that would allow that image to be 100% at load and then fade down to 15%?

Answer (score 0):

There is CSS opacity and CSS transitions, but for this I am going to use jquery.

1. Adjust your html{} selector to show the background like this

   ```
   html {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-image: url(/images/logos/v-alexander-logo1-04-transpart-web.gif)
   no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   }
   ```
2. I am not sure what you mean the menu doesn't show I saw the menu over the background image for sure. If you are still having this issue I would recommend using the z-index as one of your css rules for your menu ul#sdt_menu or wrapping that in a div id also and adjusting that parent div's z-index.
3. the jquery to do the opacity fade would be this http://jsfiddle.net/naeluh/XYB3u/

add this div to all the pages you want the background.

```
    <div id="background"></div>
```

add this css rule to your style.css file and take away your html{}

```
    #background{
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://va.in-design.com/images/logos/v-alexander-logo1-04-transpart-web.gif); 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index:-1;
    }
```

add this in the head of the pages you want it to fade out

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
      $(window).load(function(){
      $('#background').fadeOut(9000);
       }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked perfectly. However, in the process I seem to have messed up the scroll bars in my text divs. Not sure what is going on there. Also, the very bottom of the logo is obscured by something. I am guessing the footer. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Cheers,
Tamer

Comment: I d recommend using a framework to help your process like HTML5 Boilerplate

Twitter Bootstrap

Zurb Foundation

Skeleton

HTML KickStart it might make things easier good luck

Comment: which one would you recommend. My issue right now is that I am using a linux box and a windows 8 boxes to do development. Any of those available on both platforms. Are there sites or actual programs? Looking into it now. Thanks again for the info.

Comment: I just downloaded the boilerplate html template. Looks really cool. I will play around with these. I didn't think such a thing existed.